# Add a loading overlay on complete screen except navigation bar - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show a loading screen till the time data is fetched from server. For that I am using this code https://gist.github.com/igordeoliveirasa/78a310f0348fcad9b270 to create an overlay with an activity indicator.

But this works only if I add overlay on base `NavigationController` screen by calling

```
LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(self.navigationController?.view)
```

With which even my navigation bar also gets covered with overlay and user have no way to go back in case it is taking longer for a page to get load. If I try to use following nothing happens.

```
LoadingOverlay.shared.showOverlay(self.view)
```

Any hint or solution would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** - I am trying to create something like below, where after even a loading overlay navigation bar and Tab bar would still appear and user can make any actions over them

[image]

But on using the code of the link I provided above, and also @Cute Angel's code, what I am getting is like below, where overlay is indeed coming but it is not coming over elements I have added in base view from auto layout if I use `self.view`

[image]

How can I get this overlay on top of all elements I have added in base view of `ViewController` and leave navigation bar and tab bar without overlay

What I am trying to achieve is something like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

1. Declare Macros

   ```
   #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
   #define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
   ```
2. Declare Properties and methods in `.h`

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *processView;

   #pragma mark - Process view

   - (void)showProcess:(UIView *)view;
   - (void)hideProcess;
   ```
3. synthesise properties and define methods in `.m`

   ```
   @synthesize indicator, processView;

   #pragma mark - Process view

   - (void)showProcess:(UIView *)view
   {
       if (self.processView == nil)
       {
           self.processView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view.frame]; // If you want to cover whole screen then apply [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] as a frame
           self.processView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
           //self.processView.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;

           UIView *viewInner = [[UIView alloc] init];
           if (IS_IPHONE)
               viewInner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90);
           else
               viewInner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150);
           viewInner.center = self.processView.center;
           viewInner.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
           [viewInner.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
           [viewInner.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

           self.indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:IS_IPHONE?UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
           self.indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0, IS_IPHONE?-15:-30, viewInner.frame.size.width, viewInner.frame.size.height);
           self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
           [viewInner addSubview:self.indicator];

           UILabel *lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, viewInner.frame.size.height-(IS_IPHONE?45:70), viewInner.frame.size.width-10, IS_IPHONE?40:70)];
           lblLoading.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
           lblLoading.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
           lblLoading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
           lblLoading.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
           lblLoading.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:IS_IPHONE?15.0f:24.0f];
           lblLoading.text = @"Loading...";
           [viewInner addSubview:lblLoading];

           [self.processView addSubview:viewInner];
       }
       [view addSubview:self.processView]; // If you want to cover whole screen then add it to [self.window addSubview:self.processView]
       [self performSelector:@selector(createProcess) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
   }

   - (void)createProcess
   {
       [self.indicator startAnimating];
   }

   - (void)hideProcess
   {
       [self.indicator performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
       [self.processView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
   }
   ```
4. When you want to show and hide

   ```
   YourClassName * classObject = [[YourClassName alloc] init];
   [classObject showProcess:self.view];

   [classObject hideProcess];
   ```

And For swift :
1. Declare variables

```
var processView: UIView?
var indicator: UIActivityIndicatorView?
```

2. Define methods

```
// MARK: - Process view

func showProcess(view:UIView) {

    UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    self.processView = UIView(frame: view.frame) // // If you want to cover whole screen then apply UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds as frame
    self.processView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4)

    let viewInner = UIView()
    let lblLoading = UILabel()

    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone {

        viewInner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)
        self.indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
        self.indicator!.frame = CGRectMake(0, -15, viewInner.frame.size.width, viewInner.frame.size.height)
        lblLoading.frame = CGRectMake(5, viewInner.frame.size.height-45, viewInner.frame.size.width-10, 40)
        lblLoading.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15.0)

    }
    else {

        viewInner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)
        self.indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)
        self.indicator!.frame = CGRectMake(0, -30, viewInner.frame.size.width, viewInner.frame.size.height)
        lblLoading.frame = CGRectMake(5, viewInner.frame.size.height-70, viewInner.frame.size.width-10, 70)
        lblLoading.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(24.0)
    }

    viewInner.center = self.processView!.center
    viewInner.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.7)
    viewInner.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    viewInner.layer.masksToBounds = true

    self.indicator!.hidesWhenStopped = true
    viewInner.addSubview(self.indicator!)

    lblLoading.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    lblLoading.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    lblLoading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    lblLoading.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    lblLoading.text = "Loading..."
    viewInner.addSubview(lblLoading)

    self.processView!.addSubview(viewInner)

    view.addSubview(self.processView!) // If you want to cover whole screen then add it to self.window.addSubview(self.processView)
    self.performSelector("createProcess", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
}

func createProcess() {

    self.indicator?.startAnimating()
}

func hideProcess() {

    self.indicator?.performSelector("stopAnimating", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
    self.processView?.performSelector("removeFromSuperview", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
}
```

And call when you need

```
var classObject = YourClass()
classObject.showProcess(self.view)

classObject.hideProcess()
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am using Swift 2, could you please provide me suggestion into that?

Comment: I am getting error with `showProcess` and `hideProcess` methods, `AppDelegate` has no member `showProcess` and `AppDelegate` has no member `hideProcess` respectively

Comment: Have you implement this code perfectly? Please check again.

Comment: Use your class object to call the method where you have define methods

Comment: Same issue I am experiencing with your code. Overlay is coming, and it is below navigation bar as required but it is not coming on top of elements I have added in my view like `UITableView`, `UIImageView` etc. that I have added on top of base **view** using AutoLayout

Comment: See I have commented code for covering whole screen

Comment: If you want to cover whole screen, then replace line `self.processView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)` and `self.window.addSubview(self.processView!)`

Comment: I have added screenshots to explain problem, please have a look